# Does the Jericho HTML parser work on Google App Engine for Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, html-parsing

I just wanted to know, does Jericho HTML Parser work on Google App Engine?

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT :-) (I've fixed it for you. We also don't do salutations or signatures here on SO.) I also added a couple of tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Jericho HTML parser on App Engine. However I have used [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) instead which has similar functionality. If you can live with a different library you can give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

grepcode said that it is partially supported
http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.htmlparser.jericho/jericho-html/3.1